# Unity - Android - Read image from phone storage

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a script that is supposed to upload an image.
Here is what I have so far:

```
//This is how I am calling the UploadImage function
yield return StartCoroutine(UploadImage(Application.persistentDataPath + "/DCIM/Camera/20180209_210616.jpg"));

//This is the function itself
IEnumerator UploadImage(string filepath){
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        Debug.Log (bytes.Length);
        form.AddField ("submit", filepath);
        form.AddBinaryData ("fileToUpload", bytes, "sp.jpeg", "image/jpg");
        Debug.Log (form);

        WWW www = new WWW (UploadImageURL, form);

    yield return www;
    if (www.error == null) {
        Debug.Log ("Upload done " + www.isDone);
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Error " + www.error);
    }
}
```

It all works perfectly when I'm executing this code on my computer and I'm passing something like "C:/sp.jpg" to the UploadImage() function.

The moment I try this on my phone, it doesn't work anymore, I assume something is wrong with the filepath but I don't understand what.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
You may forget to add this permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @bilal1409 thanks for the answer, I'm using Unity though, I haven't written any manifest. Is that something I'm supposed to do?

Comment: You can do that from the Player Settings in Unity. Change Write Permission to External and it will add that to the Manifest for you. By the way, I don't think this is the problem. You did not explain what exactly is not working so it is impossible to help you. Use `Debug.Log` to find out which part of your code is not working.

Comment: @Programmer I have already changed the write permission in Unity. I have added debug log and it looks like the the function errors at this point  byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath); if I do a check like File.Exists() it returns True so it is reading something

Comment: Please read my comment again. It is only explaining how to do what @bilal1409 mentioned since you didn't know how to do that in Unity. I even mentioned that this is not the problem....

Comment: @Programmer yeah, sorry but I pressed Enter and it posted the comment saying "I have already changed the write permission in Unity" then I edited it to explain where the function fails. Is this information any useful?

Comment: I don't know where the problem is but I can try to help you to find a solution.
Can you try to add this File.ReadAllBytes("file:///" + path);

Comment: Check the length of that array to make sure it is reading something .What's the output of `Debug.Log(bytes.Length)`. You also have two logs for your `WWW` request. Which one of those logs in the `if` statement is showing? Without these it is hard to help you. On the server, do you get anything? Empty image? Anything at-all?

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong: when I perform a File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/DCIM/Camera/20180209_210616.jpg" it returns False so I'm definitely NOT pointing at the correct place. So how do I determine the path of a file in the Android filesystem? @bilal1409 I'm going to try that now

Comment: It looks to me you are trying to access images on the device.  You can't with this current method. `Application.persistentDataPath` points to a folder in your application.This would have worked if created the file `Application.persistentDataPath + "/DCIM/Camera/20180209_210616.jpg` via code. You need to make a plugin to access data outside your application folder or on the filesystem.

Comment: @Programmer thanks, this clears things out a lot

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, you should add a loadimage system to your program to know if that path really leads to that one: use the one I use, it doesn't bother me XD:

```
http://www.mediafire.com/file/id6lrsg4elxoajm/WindowUtility.cs/file
```

edit:

It's 100% mine and it doesn't bother me, don't worry